# Failed to assign a dict with key of type int to EasyDict

Tags: python, dictionary

I use `EasyDict` and want to assign a `dict` with key of type `int` to it

```
from easydict import EasyDict as edict
cfg = edict()
cfg.tt = {'0': 'aeroplane'}  # this is ok
cfg.tt = {0: 'aeroplane'}  # this raises error, but this is what I want to use!
```

How should I do if I wanna assign the `dict` I want, thanks

Comment: Then why are you using easydict? My understanding is that easydict is specifically for string keys.

Comment: Please provide the error

Comment: @khelwood, while i agree, in this example isnt the easydict key just "tt" ?

Comment: @tomgalpin I'm assuming there's a nested dictionary? where the internal dictionary is a standard Python dictionary?

Comment: @VishakhaLall this was my thoughts too, so would be interesting to see the error message

Comment: @tomgalpin When you put a dict into an easydict it converts it to another easydict. [source](https://github.com/makinacorpus/easydict/blob/master/easydict/__init__.py#L124)

Comment: error message: TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'int'

Comment: You should be able to achieve your required dictionary using the standard Python dictionary. Also, why is there a requirement of int keys, you can always convert str to int.

Comment: I want to use  cfg.tt[0] = 'a', cfg.tt[1] = 'b' , ... etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `EasyDict` is converting any value of `dict` to an `EasyDict`.  And making an attribute out of the keys.  `int` values cannot be attributes so this won't work.  You can install `PermissiveDict`, which does much the same as `EasyDict` but does not try to convert values to it's own type.

```
pip install permissive-dict
```

Your example:

```
from permissive_dict import PermissiveDict
cfg = PermissiveDict()
cfg.tt = {'0': 'aeroplane'}  # this is ok
cfg.tt = {0: 'aeroplane'}  # this does not raise errors, but this is what I want to use!

cfg.tt[0]) == cfg.TT[0] == cfg.tT[0] == cfg.Tt[0] == 'aeroplane'
```